# Cursor while loop returning every value but the last

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-cursor

I am using a while loop to iterate through a cursor and then outputing the longitude and latitude values of every point within the database.

For some reason it is not returning the last (or first depending on if I use Cursor.MoveToLast) set of longitude and latitude values in the cursor.

Here is my code:

```
public void loadTrack() {
SQLiteDatabase db1 = waypoints.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor trackCursor = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, "trackidfk=1", null, null, null,ORDER_BY); 

    trackCursor.moveToFirst();
    while (trackCursor.moveToNext()) {
        Double lat = trackCursor.getDouble(2);
        Double lon = trackCursor.getDouble(1);
        //overlay.addGeoPoint( new GeoPoint( (int)(lat*1E6),  (int)(lon*1E6)));
        System.out.println(lon);
        System.out.println(lat);
    }
}
```

From this I am getting:

```
*******************************************
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 3.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 5.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 4.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 5.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 5.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 5.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 4.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 4.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 3.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 3.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 2.0
04-02 15:39:07.416: INFO/System.out(10551): 2.0
04-02 15:39:07.493: INFO/System.out(10551): 1.0
04-02 15:39:07.493: INFO/System.out(10551): 1.0
***************************************************************
7 Sets of values, where I should be getting 8 sets.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

moveToNext() has two features.  It returns a boolean signifying that there *is* a next, but at the same time it goes ahead and moves the cursor.

```
public void loadTrack() {
SQLiteDatabase db1 = waypoints.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor trackCursor = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, "trackidfk=1", null, null, null,ORDER_BY); 

    trackCursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        Double lat = trackCursor.getDouble(2);
        Double lon = trackCursor.getDouble(1);
        //overlay.addGeoPoint( new GeoPoint( (int)(lat*1E6),  (int)(lon*1E6)));
        System.out.println(lon);
        System.out.println(lat);
    } while (trackCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: You probably want something in to make sure there is a first element though, that probably won't go too well if it ever ends up in an empty one.

Answer (score 5):

```
Cursor c=null;
c=......;
try {
    if (c!=null) {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        }

    }
} finally {
    if (c!=null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your skipping the first value actually, not the last.

```
trackCursor.moveToFirst();
while (trackCursor.moveToNext()) {
```

The first time into the while loop you are pointing at the 2nd row.

I would convert your [while loop to a do-while loop](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: I tried the do while, but as the number of rows returned could be any number I wasn't sure what the while expression should be?

Comment: do {...} while (trackCursor.moveToNext())  It's the same while expression that you are currently using.

Answer (score 3):

You just executed the query. Can't you just get rid of the moveToFirst()?

```
public void loadTrack() {
SQLiteDatabase db1 = waypoints.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor trackCursor = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM, "trackidfk=1", null, null, null,ORDER_BY); 

    while (trackCursor.moveToNext()) {
        Double lat = trackCursor.getDouble(2);
        Double lon = trackCursor.getDouble(1);
        //overlay.addGeoPoint( new GeoPoint( (int)(lat*1E6),  (int)(lon*1E6)));
        System.out.println(lon);
        System.out.println(lat);
    }
}
```