# Android Sql NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I have a little issue with Android SQL queries.

Here is the my code :

```
        Communicator rpc;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, "oops_sys_tpl.sqlite", null, 1);
        dbHelper.getDatabase();
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "id", "75");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "objectId", "2");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users","serverName","ooops.com");
        dbHelper.executeQuery("users", "username", "muphet");

        newServerName = "stampii.com";
        Log.w("UserId","Show user Id : "+userId);
        int uuId = rpc.localUserIdByServerUserId(userId,newServerName);
        Log.w("uuId","uuId : "+uuId);
```

In Communicator class :

```
public static int localUserIdByServerUserId(int serverUserId){

    String query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE objectId = "+serverUserId+" LIMIT 1";
    Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    result.get(dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query));

    int uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(0).toString());
    return uuid;
}

public static int localUserIdByServerUserId(int serverUserId, String serverName){

    String query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE objectId = "+serverUserId+" AND serverName = "+serverName+" LIMIT 1";
    Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    result.get(dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query));

    int uuid = Integer.parseInt(result.get(0).toString());
    Log.w("localUSerByIdServerUserId","LocalUserByIdServerUserId result : "+uuid);
    return uuid;
}
```

In DatabaseHelper class :

```
SQLIteDatabase sqliteDb;
   public boolean executeQuery(String tableName,String keys,String value){
        return execQuery(tableName,keys,value);
    }

    private static boolean execQuery(String tableName,String key,String value){
        sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(key, value);
        sqliteDb.insert(tableName, null, values);

        return true;

    }
```

And it's throwin me a NullPointerException at :

```
result.get(dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query));
```

Any suggestions how can I fix that?

Comment: Would help you if those statements were on different lines to show exactly where the NPE comes from. As it is, it must be the `dbHelper` as `result` gets assigned to a new `HashMap` immediately above. So `dbHelper` is `null`. Find out if your `dbHelper` creation code is getting executed before the NPE, and find out if anything is setting `dbHelper` to null, either directly or indirectly. Also, I don't know what `result.get(dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query))` is meant to achieve as the result `Map` will be empty, and so that use of `Map.get` doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: So how can I put the result of dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query) in a Map,ArrayList or anything that will work?

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567594/cursor-while-loop-returning-every-value-but-the-last - for how to iterate through a query's results. Take the items from ech row you need, and put them in an `ArrayList` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that you are calling in this line : `result.get(dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(query));` and the method which you show here `public boolean executeQuery()` are different one, so I guess the problem is in the other one.Check it and you will find the answer,or paste it here so we can help you.